# Compressing game save data

Tags: compression

I'm writing a game that needs to save a lot of detailed data (exact trajectories of some entities) to an external file. I want to save drive space and bandwidth by compressing it, but I've never done this, so I don't know if there is a preferred way to do it.

Of course the compression-decompression should not affect the speed of the game too much.

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [zlib](http://zlib.net/) library has bindings for most programming languages, and is quite fast. However, you should compare various comperssion algorithms, because one algorithm may achieve better compression rates on *your* kind of data than on the general case.

Answer (score 1):

One, possibly extreme way of compressing data is to record only the steps/inputs used to create it. Something like what ModNation Racer does (curse those long loading times as it re-creates the track). (Google for videos of the track editor in ModNation Racer).

i.e. if i was storing some terrain, i'd store all the manipulations starting from a flat plain. i.e. apply the volcano shaped brush with this force, here. Apply the terrain smoothing operation over this area, with this force. Add my predefined object here. Using bezier-curve-like curves with 'key-frames' to construct an entire track/flight path/whatever.

Many other games do this sort of thing not just for level loading, but for gameplay too, by making the game deterministic, sending only player inputs (i think PixelJunk Shooter 2 does this).